# date.future? is sometimes incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a validation that involved checking if a `compdate` field is in the future. The `compdate` field is of type date.   The custom validation for this looks like this

```
class Game
  validate :compdate_not_in_future

 def compdate_not_in_future
    return if compdate.nil?
    return unless compdate.future?
    errors.add(:compdate, 'cannot be in the future')
  end
end
```

I tested this with rspec tests like this.

```
it { expect(build(:game, compdate: Date.today).valid?).to be true }
it { expect(build(:game, compdate: 1.day.from_now.to_date).valid?).to be true }
```

These tests can fail, depending on the time of day. I suspect it is due to the relationship of my timezone to UTC.  How to I test this and correct the validator so that whatever timezone the user it in, it will work as expected, e.g. if a user enters a compdate that is today in their timezone, the validation will pass, if it is a date greater than today in their timezone it will fail.

Comment: Checkout [use_zone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-use_zone)

Comment: Is it just your tests that are invalid, or is there a bug outside of the tests that isn't captured here?

Comment: Another suggestion in addition to @mark 's suggestion is to use [time cop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) in your tests in order to prevent temporal inconsistencies in your tests. That can happen very often in these types of tests where you are truncating the time portion and just using a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments added to the question and this [post](http://quipper.github.io/2016/02/12/how-to-tame-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails.html), I came up with the following solution.

I introduced a method `match_zone` that had the time zone the game was played in. Then the class had

```
class Game
  validate :compdate_not_in_future

 def compdate_not_in_future
    return if compdate.nil?
    Time.use_zone(match_zone) do
       return unless compdate.future?
    end
    errors.add(:compdate, 'cannot be in the future')
  end
end
```

and the tests were like this:

```
it { expect(build(:game, compdate: Time.use_zone(match_zone) { Date.current }).valid?).to be true }

it { expect(build(:game, compdate: Time.use_zone(match_zone) { Date.current + 1.day}).valid?).to be true }
```